# Does WebRTC causes any load on the broadcaster site?

Tags: android, webrtc

Imagine someone is broadcasting an audio or video world wide through WebRTC i.e one to many communication (app like periscope which i think is not done using WebRTC). Will it get affected by the broadcasters less bandwidth ? will it increase the load on broadcaster side causing loss of packets which will decrease quality of communication ? As this topic is new and very little content is available on net please suggest some good books and online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC facilitates peer to peer communication. Going by this login a simple WebRTC broadcast application will heavily depend on broadcaster's bandwidth as the number of recipients will be same to the number of outbound media streams.

This is one of the main reasons why WebRTC Gateways or Media Servers or similar terms have been developed. In this case the broadcaster simply sends a single stream to the intermediary Gateway or Server and the other recipients then connect to the Gateway or Server and receive the stream from there.

To put it in simple terms, you basically add a central WebRTC client to which everyone connects.

You can read more at [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/), [Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/), etc.

Or find official RTCPeerConnection documentation [here](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/).